# AWS EC2 : IAM policy to allow inbound SecurityGroup with PORT Range

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, security-groups

I want to allow the access to specific ec2 security group to one of the developer. For that I know that we can use something like this :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1413232782000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [               
                "ec2:DescribeInstanceAttribute",
                "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkAcls",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups"              
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1413232782001",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",                
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:<accountid>:security-group/sg-<id>"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But Now, I also need to control what inbound ports developer shall add to this security group. For example I want to allow the developer to add only 80, 8080, 443  . Not other ports .Is this possible ?

Thank You.